# label the X axis in a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting chart with weekdays

Tags: c#

The x dimension of my graph is composed of double values which contain the number of minutes. They cover a range of 1 week. While I have no problem with correctly displaying those values on the graph, I would like the X-axis labels to be week-days (the hour:minute precision is not important on the labels, but is present on the graph, because monday at 15:00 is a point between monday and tuesday, but placed before the points monday at 16:00, for example). Any idea how I can achieve this?

PS: the mentioned values in minutes are obtained from: #(day of week)*24*60 + hours*60 + minutes, where #(day of week) = 0 for monday, 1 for tuesday, ...

Answer (score 2):

I have been analyzing the Microsoft code samples here: [Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61#content). The behavior you wish may be accomplished by either option below:

1. Using multiple Y axes ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFnj.png)) with realignment of your data. Implies having a  copy of you original data points. Then just modify axis properties for your second series. Full code available in the samples. Obviously you have to do that for the X axis.
2. Using primary and secondary axes: AxisX and AxisX2.
3. Using custom labels ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZb5Q.png)). Code sample available at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the corresponding Axis IntervalType of the ChartArea to Days - assuming it is ok for you to have to transform minutes to days. You state the core idea here is to have a "time" based graph, no matter whether its minutes or days simply divide minutes by /(60[minutes]*24[hours])

Your desire for bigger time spans can be accomplished by calculating minutes related to a fixed start time/date.

```
var chartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
            {
                Name = "ChartArea1",
                AxisX = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis
                {
                    IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Days
                }
            };

            //...//
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
```